# Uploading files to a storage server from a web app

Tags: php, ftp, vps

I have a webapp where by people are allowed to upload files, the webapp and upload form run on VPS1(24GB) I have another server called VPS2(1TB). I want user to use the webapp to upload files and for the files to be stored on the VPS2. How ever I'm not sure the best way to do this, would I upload the file to VPS1 and then transfer it to VPS2 via FTP(or other methods)? Or should I upload it directly to VPS2 using a post method on a webserver running on VPS2? This has to be scalable, I will be adding more webservers in the future.

I had thoughts about putting all the storage VPS servers in an array in PHP an array and randomly selecting which one to post files to. But I'm not sure, really lost and would like some advanced help.

Comment: as i think and for examlpe: u have /upload/image/ to upload image on VPS1. but rewrite rule redirects it to VPS2 which have easy and light uploading script. am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can post your files to your vps2 php script and store files there, Thats a good option and for scalability you can choose which server to choose depending on nearest location of server for clients or randomly choose one. this is the best option i see here, And rest work is your database.

2.Also you can backup a certain amount of files to your vps2 server using linux script when the disk is full using their local ip in case you have a local ip to share with other server.

But still first option is better, you can have different subdomains for the different web server like vps1.domain.com/file01 and vps2.domain.com/file02 and similarly other, and obviously script on different servers depends on sessions ,cookies , database.